# pysnmp-4.4.4 not available in source path

Tags: pysnmp

pysnmp-4.4.4.tar.gz is not available in the following path
https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pysnmp/pysnmp-4.4.4.tar.gz

but I am able to get older releases.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has something to do with the recent PyPI overhaul. But the package is available through both [web UI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysnmp/4.4.4) and [pip](https://pypi.python.org/packages/26/0f/a85f1b0271d9941c3b90504342b29ae6ad6670d88db62a8c6dc2c363b0cd/pysnmp-4.4.4.tar.gz).

Where do you get this direct link? May be it is not stable and should not be hardcoded anywhere?

Comment: actually my application supported pysnmp 4.2.5  and the download path is working for the same 
I was planning to use the latest pysnmp (4.4.4) but now when I change the version of the download path it doesnot work